# TypeScript complains about HTMLElement do not have value property

Tags: javascript, typescript

TypeScript complains about HTMLElement do not have value property but when I use it in JavaScript it works fine.

```
 var inputValue: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('input1');
 console.log(inputValue.value); // show error message
```

In JavaScript, 
    var inputValue= document.getElementById('input1');
    console.log(inputValue.value); // it gives me the value of input element

Can I know why TypeScript complains?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[HTMLElement](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L8248) doesn't have the `value` member, the [HTMLInputElement](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L9158) does.
You need to type assert it:

```
var inputValue = document.getElementById('input1') as HTMLInputElement;
console.log(inputValue.value); // should be ok
```

---

#### Edit

The typescript definitions represent actual javascript dom elements, in this case for [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) and [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. why as HTMLInputElement?

Comment: Where does as come from? JavaScript or TypeScript?

Comment: Check the revised answer