# ng build --watch is not outputting dist directory if there is a transpilation error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular-cli, ng-build

I have this command in my terminal

```
$ ng build --watch
Date: 2018-01-02T21:42:45.851Z                                                      
Hash: f72a8ce7baf664dc5d5a
Time: 3260ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 5.83 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 303 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 323 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 57.9 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in src/main.ts(50,42): error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.
```

How can I force transpilation even with an error using `ng build`? I want angular-cli to always output the target files to the `dist` director no matter what.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore Typescript Errors "property does not exist on value of type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083389/ignore-typescript-errors-property-does-not-exist-on-value-of-type)

Comment: not a dupe of that issue, I need to ignore all errors at the command line so transpilation always happens

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45028233/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-htmlelement-for-textarea-angular

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497187/typescript-complains-about-htmlelement-do-not-have-value-property

Comment: Relates to (discussion) https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11051

Answer (score 1):

The recommended method is to use a type assertion:

```
let inputFields = document.getElementsByClassName("settings") as HTMLInputElement
```

As described in this [TypeScript bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10453).

Based on the `angular-cli` [configuration options](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build), there is no way to suppress errors during build.

You need to either fix your TypeScript code using a type assertion, cast the variable to type `any`, or use configuration flags in your `tsconfig.json` file - such as `"compilerOptions":{ "noImplicitAny":false }` which you can [read more about here.](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/options/noImplicitAny.html)

For a full list of TypeScript complier options, see:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: for the sake of all people reading this, which config options in tsconfig.json should people use to ignore errors